# LinearGradientBrush on Image not working and not getting more transparent towards the bottom

Tags: image, maui, linear-gradients, lineargradientbrush

I wanted to load an Image which is basically in a very dark like black-isch Color and add a LinearGradientBrush to it, so that it gets more which to the Bottom.

In a Grid, I used an Image and added the following LinearGradientBrush from "Transparent" at the top (to see the image in original colors) to "White" a the bottom to see it getting more "transparent" to my white ContentPage background:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" 
       Grid.Column="0" 
       Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
       Source="myImage.jpg" 
       Aspect="AspectFill" 
       HeightRequest="300"
       x:Name="myImage">

    <Image.Background>
        <!-- StartPoint defaults to (0,0) -->
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1" />
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Image.Background>

</Image>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work at all and I see the original image without gradient:

[image]

I also tried a LinearGradientBrush with different Colors on my Background to see if it is working with these values at all:

[image: LinearGradient with 2 Colors]

**Expected**:
What I wanted to see is a LinearGradient as in the Background-Image here, so that the Image gets more trasparent to the Bottom. I also believe, that this Gradient should end earlier from top to bottom so that it gets white earlier then. Maybe could also work with a smaller height of the Image, don't know what's the best option:

[image]

============= Another try... =======================

I tried with with this [Photo][4] which I renamed to myImage.jpg

Here, I use a Grid and place the photo and the ScrollView into the same Row/Column. Also tried with ZIndex.

Seems like the impact of the Gradient-Brush is not smooth enough here. At the very top it is too foggy and at the very bottom not fading out to white enough. Do you understand this Gradient enough to explain how

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*" ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                
    <Image Grid.Row="0" 
           Grid.Column="0" 
           Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
           Source="myImage.jpg" 
           Aspect="AspectFill" 
           HeightRequest="500"
           x:Name="myImage" />
    
    <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="800" Margin="0, -190, 0, 0">
        
        <ScrollView.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <!--<RadialGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>-->
        </ScrollView.Background>
        
    </ScrollView>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tested `Image` or `Frame` [Officially provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/brushes/lineargradient?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-vertical-linear-gradient), but failed like yours.

You want this [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea9q3.jpg)?

You can set child element background linear gradient:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"
             x:Name="this"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
             BackgroundImageSource="ddd.png"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

   <ScrollView>
        <ScrollView.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent"
                          Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="White"
                          Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ScrollView.Background>

        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">            
         
            <!--<Image Source="ddd.png">
                <Image.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1.0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Image.Background>
            </Image>-->


           <Button Text="Open window" Command="{Binding Source={x:Static local:ViewModel.Instance}, Path=OpenNewWindowCommand}"/>
           <Button Text="Show alert" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

       </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

**Update**

About *The Gradient is not "smooth" enough, though.* Like ewerspej said, you can add more GradientStop objects. Refer to 
[Create a vertical linear gradient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/brushes/lineargradient?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-vertical-linear-gradient):

> Then, add two or more GradientStop objects to the `LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops` collection, that specify the colors in the gradient and their positions.

Comment: Basically, yes this is the effect I want to achieve. Currently, when I use BackgroundImageSource of the ContentPage it is getting streched, unfortunately.

I am also wondering, if I could use it with a Grid and Image is in a Grid? That's currently not possible. Also tried as you did with a Frame with a negative Margin to the top, but does not provide the result.

Do you have any clue why this must be a Child-Element since it does also limit possibilities to experiment with <Image ... declarations.

Is there also a way to stop Gradiation earlier so that full white is shown earlier?

Comment: 1. *It is getting stretched.* For MAUI, you need to set the size of the source image. 2. *Do you have any clue why this must be a Child-Element since it does also limit possibilities to experiment with <Image ... declarations.* MAUI has a hierarchical display order, the parent element is displayed at the bottom, and the child element is displayed at the top. Only color linear gradient, not direct image linear gradient. You can look [this](https://imgur.com/a/RrynGoU).

Comment: In a ContentPage, I do not see a Size-Attribute for a BackgroundImageSource that is used in the answer above. When I try to use your solution in any kind of Grid or other Layout, it won't apply it.

I understand, it has to be a Child and is kind of Stacked from Botton to Top when new children are added. But, an Image does not allow to set one of the Layouts as child where I can apply your gradient effect (which is absolutely what I want)

Comment: 1. *I do not see a Size-Attribute for a BackgroundImageSource that is used in the answer above.* I mean in the beginning you have to crop the size of the image.

Comment: Do you mean crop the size of the original image or do you see a way doing it by code? As soon as I assign the "Background = img.Source" for instance in Code, it gets streched. Really annoying to be honest that MAUI is restricting so many options

Comment: @OXO *Do you mean crop the size of the original image or do you see a way doing it by code?* Yes, and I agree that “Really annoying to be honest that MAUI is restricting so many options”. 

Comment: Okay, then I‘ll give that a try. The reason I did not want to do that was the different resolutions of devices including an iPhone vs. iPad when run on them, too. I like your solution and also understand your explanation. Based on that, is there other controls or layouts that can have  the parent-child-relationship you mentioned and can stack an Image? Maybe also have it below the actual Image and a negative Margin of the gradient upwards into the Image?

Comment: Added another try to the original question with a Grid, which also seems to be a possibility. The Gradient is not "smooth" enough, though.

Comment: Absolutely, have accepted it. Great answers by the way 

Answer (score 0):

You could set more `<GradientStop>` items into the `<LinearGradientBrush>`:

```xml
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.0" />
    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.3" />
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.7" />
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

That way you can control the interpolation between Transparent and White. Play around with the different `Offset` values and the amount of stops to see if you can achieve the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint. I will play around. Probably looks better if whitening starts later and at the very end fades out more 